# Is that possible to use control M to orchestrate Azure Data factory Jobs

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, control-m

Is that possible to use control M to orchestrate Azure Data factory Jobs?
I found this agent that can be installed on an VM:
https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/bmc-software.ctm-agent-linux-arm

But I didn't find documentation about it.
Cal Control M call an REST API to run and monitor a Job? I could user Azure functions and Blobs to control it.

Answer (score 0):

All Control-M components can be installed and operated on Azure (and most other cloud infrastructure). Either use the link you quote or alternatively deploy Agents using Control-M Automation API (AAPI) or a combination of the two.

So long as you are on a fairly recent version Control-M you can do most operational tasks, for example you can monitor a job like so -

> ctm run jobs:status::get -s "jobid=controlm:00001"

The Control-M API is developing quickly, check out the documentation linked from here -

https://docs.bmc.com/docs/automation-api/9019100monthly/services-872868740.html#Control-MAutomationAPI-Services-ctmrunjob:status::get

Also see -

https://github.com/controlm/automation-api-quickstart http://controlm.github.io https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/workloadautomation/Control-M+Automation+API+-+Services https://52.32.170.215:8443/automation-api/swagger-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

***At this time***, I don't believe you will find any out of the box connectors for Control-M to Azure Data Factory integration. You do have some other options, though!

---

### Proxy ADF Yourself

You can write the glue code for this, essentially being the mediator between the two.

1. Write a program that will invoke the ADF REST API to run a pipeline.
   [Details Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#rest-api)
2. After triggering the pipeline, then write the code for monitoring for status.
   [Details Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-rest-api#monitor-pipeline)
3. Have Control-M call your code via an Agent that has access to it.

   - I've done this with a C# console app running on a local server, and a Control-M Agent that invokes the glue code.
   - [Control-M Documentation here](http://documents.bmc.com/supportu/9.0.19/help/Plugins/en-US/Azure/Web_Help/index.htm#97591.htm) also allows a way for you to execute an Azure Function directly from Control-M. This means you could put your code in an Azure Function.
     [Details Here](http://documents.bmc.com/supportu/9.0.19/help/Plugins/en-US/Azure/Web_Help/index.htm#97591.htm)'

---

### **ALTERNATIVE METHOD**

For a "no code" way, check out this [Logic App connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatafactory).
Write a logic app to [run the pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatafactory/#create-a-pipeline-run) and [get the pipeline run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatafactory/#get-a-pipeline-run) to monitor status in a loop.

Next, Control-M should be able to use [a plugin](http://documents.bmc.com/supportu/9.0.19/help/Plugins/en-US/Azure/Web_Help/index.htm#97560.htm) to invoke the logic app.

---

### Notes

**Note that Control-M required an [HTTP Trigger](http://documents.bmc.com/supportu/9.0.19/help/Plugins/en-US/Azure/Web_Help/index.htm#97591.htm) for Azure Functions and Logic Apps.
**You might also be able to take advantage of the [Control-M Web Services plugin](http://documents.bmc.com/supportu/9.0.19/help/Plugins/en-US/BPI/Web_Help/index.htm#39457.htm). Though, in my experience, I wasn't impressed with the lack of support for different authentication methods.

***Hope this helps!***

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this post so a bit late to the party.

Control-M includes Application Integrator which enables you to use integrations created by others and to either enhance them or build your own. You can use REST or cli to instruct Control-M what requests should be generated to an application when a job is started, during execution and monitoring and how to analyze results and collect output.

A public repository accessible from Application Integrator shows existing jobs and there is one for Data Factory. I have extended it a bit so that the the Data Factory is started and monitored to completion via REST but then a Powershell script is invoked to retrieve the pipeline run information for each activity within the pipeline.

I've posted that job and script in https://github.com/JoeGoldberg/automation-api-community-solutions/tree/master/4-ai-job-type-examples/CTM4AzureDataFactory but the README is coming later.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer: Control-M now has a fully supported integration with Azure Data Factory. Docs can be found here: https://docs.bmc.com/docs/ctm_integrations/control-m-for-azure-data-factory-994589887.html